# Ошибка в пропсах но я помоему все правильно сделал

Tags: reactjs

```
 import React from 'react'
import s from './CardItem.module.css'

const CardItem = () => {
  return (
    <div className={s.card}>
        <div className={s.card__img}>{props.img}</div>
        <div className={s.card__line}></div>
        <div className={s.card__title}>{props.title}</div>
        <div className={s.card__text}>{props.text}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export{CardItem}
-----------------------
import React from 'react'
import s from './CardList.module.css'
import {CardItem} from './CardItem/CardItem'

const cards = [
    {
        title: 'Our bissines',
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sagittis feugiat laoreet. Donec sit amet pretium nisl. Nulla quis quam ac felis porta volutpat quis ut leo. Mauris ullamcorper venenatis nulla, vitae iaculis erat tincidunt ut. Sed lectus nulla, vehicula ac diam ut, imperdiet consectetur magna. Integer hendrerit placerat pretium. Curabitur consectetur ligula mauris, a vestibulum sapien scelerisque eget. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent ac suscipit sapien.',
        img: 'https://hurix.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Picture5-553x400.png'
    },
    {
        title: 'Our team',
        text: 'Lorem  f Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridic.',
        img: 'https://www.planymerka.com/images/imagen%20premium.png'
    }
]

export const CardList = () => {
  return (
    <div className={s.wrapper}>
        {
            cards.map(card =>{
                return <CardItem title={card.title} text={card.text} img={card.img}/>
            })
        }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Поделетесь ошибкой? Пока могу предположить, что это связано с тем, что вы не передаете пропсы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо вам надо добавить параметр `props` в компоненту

```
const CardItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={s.card}>
        <div className={s.card__img}>{props.img}</div>
        <div className={s.card__line}></div>
        <div className={s.card__title}>{props.title}</div>
        <div className={s.card__text}>{props.text}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

P.S:

```
cards.map(card =>{
                return <CardItem title={card.title} text={card.text} img={card.img}/>
            })
```

Вот сюда еще нужно добавить `key`. Почитать можно [здесь](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Например: `<CardItem key={card.id} title={card.title} text={card.text} img={card.img}/>`

Comment: Спасибо я понял забыл ключи